# How do I meck the same function with multiple sets of parameter values?

Tags: erlang, eunit, meck

I'm trying to meck out a call to [`application:get_env`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#get_env-2), but I'm testing a function that calls it with two different sets of arguments.

I setup two separate `meck:expect` calls like this, but when the function I'm testing tries to call `application:get_env(my_app, my_param_one)` it fails and throws `error:function_clause` with `undefined`.

```
meck:expect(application, get_env, fun(my_app, my_param_one) -> {ok, "my_value_one"} end),
meck:expect(application, get_env, fun(my_app, my_param_two) -> {ok, "my_value_two"} end),
```

How can I meck out the same function, with differents sets of parameter values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `meck` is overwriting the first.

Whenever you define a function in Erlang by pattern-matching on different sets of values, you separate each set of patterns with a semicolon, like this:

```
-module(sample).

-export([create_greeting/2]).

create_greeting("Grant", _Greeting) -> io:format("Good day sir!");
create_greeting(Name, Greeting) -> io:format("~s, ~s!", [Greeting, Name]).
```

Similarly, when you setup your `meck` statements, define the function once, but separate each set of patterns/arguments with a semicolon, like this:

```
meck:expect(application, get_env, fun(my_app, my_param_one) -> {ok, "my_value_one"};
                                     (my_app, my_param_two) -> {ok, "my_value_two"}
                                  end),
```